# Can php/laravel batch update()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Supposed I'm creating a bank management system.
I want to make some of users' account activated. So I can...

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
User::where(function($enq) use($ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id)
        $enq->orwhere('id', $id);
})->update(['activated'=>true]);
```

But how about making their money autoincrese $10 ?

```
    $ids = [1, 2, 3];
User::where(function($enq) use($ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id)
        $enq->orwhere('id', $id);
})->update(function(){
    //what should I write here??? maybe I can write
    //$this_obj->money+=10;
});
```

The biggest problem is that, I can't get the "current object" inside the update().
My English is not very well, I hope my description won't confused anyone.
And I hope to get a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query builder includes an increment method that could handle this:

```
User::whereIn('id', $ids)->increment('money', 10);
```

Note that I also used the whereIn method as a simple replacement of your loop of orwhere calls.

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_increment

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the solution! May I ask something more...If the 'money' is not an integer, but a string. eg, ["100","200"], this is a string encoded by json, means the user has 2 accounts. How can I make the string become to ["110","210"]

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Eloquent Model provides increment method for incrementing a column's value by a given amount:  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L389`

What you can do:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
User::where(function($enq) use($ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id)
        $enq->orwhere('id', $id);
})->increment('money', 10);
```

Or even better:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
User::whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->increment('money', 10);
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the solution! May I ask something more...If the 'money' is not an integer, but a string. eg, ["100","200"], this is a string encoded by json, means the user has 2 accounts. How can I make the string become to ["110","210"]